# App object should be initialized before loading root widget (Multiple Screens and Separated Files) in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm having problems in properly handling the error since I have multiple screens that are separated on other .py files which also does a Builder.load_file for their respective Kivy files. I've read some documents already that said I should put it on a build function and return it but that doesn't seem to work and load their respective Kivy files. Here is a sample of how my code goes

**Main App.py**

```python
# screen imports
from lib.login import LoginScreen
from lib.signup import SignupScreen

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name = 'login'))
        sm.add_widget(SignupScreen(name = 'signup'))

        # load mainapp kivy
        return Builder.load_file('lib/kv/mainapp.kv') 

MainApp().run()
```

**Login.py**

```python
class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def build(self):
    return Builder.load_file('lib/kv/login.kv')
```

**Signup.py**

```python
class SignupScreen(Screen):
    def build(self):
    return Builder.load_file('lib/kv/login.kv')
```

One thing I did try besides the build method was the `__init__` method which made my program work now but says I'm loading it multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! It was already working in itself and I didn't really have to put a build function on each of my separated screen files. I'm guessing, I got the App object error at first was probably because I was calling the screens outside the build function of MainApp(MDApp) class. I don't really know the specifics of what happened since I'm still new to both kivy and python.